# Is mysql auto increment for the next number or the current number?

Tags: mysql, row, auto-increment

So, say I have 4 rows

```
1 | Matt  
2 | Jack  
3 | Mike  
4 | Josh
```

what would the the auto increment value be? 4 or 5?

Comment: What do you mean, the "auto increment value"? The value stored by MySQL for the next id? That is 5.

Comment: Next time please add more tags

Comment: @Ty221 You do realize there is a comment field on the edit's for specifically that type of comment right? Also, Iirc [Stack Overflow discourages the use of ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags) such as "Row", Possibly yes I should have used the "auto-increment" tag, but running this through on a two year old question feels rather like gaming the badges to me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the next value that will be inserted, so in your example the auto increment value would be 5.

Comment: Ok, so in my example the autoincrement value would be 5?

Answer (score 0):

Actually may be you should use 
`show create table ur_table_name;` 
to see the value of  **AUTO_INCREMENT** , while this will indicate which value will be used for next insert.